# Create shortcut based on result of Pascal function

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to create a shortcut based on the result of a Pascal function (which returns a path), but can't how to do it.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
[Icons]
Name: '{userstartup}\Myprog'; Filename: MyFunctionThatReturnsPath() + 'Myprog.exe';
```

But the function is never called, instead the filename is treated as a simple string.

Comment: Use `Filename: {code:MyFunctionThatReturnsPath} + 'Myprog.exe'`

Comment: I now get "invalid prototype" on the function:


function MyFunctionThatReturnsPath():string;
.....
end;

Comment: @TLama I think your syntax is wrong. It should be `Filename: "{code:MyFunctionThatReturnsPath}\Myprog.exe"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[Icons]` section entry should look like:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\Myprog"; Filename: "{code:MyFunctionThatReturnsPath}\Myprog.exe"
```

And the corresponding function is:

```pascal
[Code]

function MyFunctionThatReturnsPath(Param: string): string;
begin
   Result := 'C:\path';
end;
```

The function must take a string argument, even if you do not actually make use of it. See [Pascal Scripting: Scripted Constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants):

> The called function must have 1 String parameter named Param, and must return a String or a Boolean value depending on where the constant is used.

Comment: I'm a total newbie to Pascal syntax (many years in the BASIC world). I knew what I wanted to do, it was just getting it right!

Many thanks for the help.